# Pass data from the first VC to the third (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, uiviewcontroller

I have 3 viewControllers and i'm passing data from the first to the second in this way (this is the first VC)

```
 var steppers : UIStepper?

    @IBOutlet weak var hourLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var stepper: UIStepper!

    @IBAction func stepper(_ sender: UIStepper) {

      hourLabel.text = String(sender.value)
    }


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let nc = segue.destination as? SelectClass {
            nc.limit = Int(stepper.value)
        } }
```

in the second VC i have the `var limit = 0`. Till here everything works well but what i want to do is to pass the value that the user gives to the stepper to the third VC. I tried to create another variable in the third VC `var limit2 = 0`and to pass the data in this way from the secondo VC to the third

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let vc = segue.destination as? ThirdClass {
            vc.limit2 = limit
        } }
```

but without results, my `var limit2 = 0`it always has the value 0 instead of taking the value that i added with the stepper. How can i do?

this is the prepare in the second VC

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == nearbySearchSegueIdentifier {
            guard let category = sender as? QCategoryy else {
                return
            }
            if let selectedRows = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {

                if let vc = segue.destination as? ThirdClass {
                vc.category = category
                vc.limit2 = limit
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you going directly from VC1 to VC3?

Comment: Did you forget to add a segue connecting the second and third VC?

Comment: @Malik no I must go through the second VC

Comment: @Sweeper no i didn't forget

Comment: Nothing seems to be wrong with your code. Try putting a break point in your `prepareForSegue` in VC2 and see if the value is being assigned

Comment: @seran try to debug this value first  :-  Int(stepper.value)

Comment: @Malik tried but it didn't call the method, i edit my question adding the prepare of the second VC

Comment: @GOPALVASANI i edited the question, adding the prepare of the second VC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Considering your current code**, its possible that *limit2* its not set because this condition is not valid:

```
// This condition could be failing sometimes
if let selectedRows = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {
    if let vc = segue.destination as? ThirdClass {
        vc.category = category
        vc.limit2 = limit
    }
}
```

According to the [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614864-indexpathsforselectedrows), `indexPathsForSelectedRows` returns an optional and in your segue, you are only setting *limit2* if that value is not nil.

**Try to set** *limit2* outside any condition, so it will be executed always and if you need to fulfill a condition in order to do a `segue`, check `shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621502-shouldperformsegue).

Also, if the value that you need on VC3 is the same that you have when you leave VC1, there are different approaches that you could use to pass the data between them without having to rely on VC2.

One could be to **create a static variable** in VC1 and set the *limit* value before pushing to VC2:

```
var steppers : UIStepper?

    @IBOutlet weak var hourLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var stepper: UIStepper!

    // ADD THIS
    static var globalLimit: Int = 0

    @IBAction func stepper(_ sender: UIStepper) {
      hourLabel.text = String(sender.value)
    }


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let nc = segue.destination as? SelectClass {
            nc.limit = Int(stepper.value)
            // AND THIS
            VC1ClassName.globalLimit = Int(stepper.value)
        } 
}
```

Then **inside VC3** load your global value whenever you want (maybe `viewDidLoad`):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    limit2 = VC1ClassName.globalLimit
}
```

Instead of having data passing through ViewControllers, you could also **create a StepperManager class** or something similar that is responsible for managing the data and you can access it from every class you need at any moment in time.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just pass if from First to Second to Third?

FirstVC:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "tosecondsegue" {
          let itemController : Second = segue.destination as! Second
          itemController.limit = 0 //Whatever you want
    }
}
```

SecondVC:

```
var limit = 0

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
       if segue.identifier == "tothirdsegue" {
            let itemController : ThirdVC = segue.destination as! ThirdVC
            itemController.limit2 = limit
       }
}
```

ThirdVC:

```
 var limit2 = 0

//Use it here now
```

Comment: "Variable used within its own initial value" i get this error on item controller.limit

Comment: What are you setting the 'itemController.limit = ' to?

Comment: itemController.limit = Int(stepper.value)

Comment: If you print  Int(stepper.value) what do u get

Comment: with the error i can't run the simulator, in the way i tried (look at my question) i get the right value of the stepper when i'm going in the second VC, but i when i go in the third VC from the second i didn't get any value so the var limit2 = 0 remains with the value of 0

Comment: So the value is lost when moving between the 2nd and 3rd VC?

Comment: Okay are you sure the prepareforsegue in secondvc is being called?

Comment: What is  if segue.identifier == nearbySearchSegueIdentifier { the nearbySeachSegueIdentifier?